# onOptionsItemSelected of fragment inside ViewPager not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have a problem with developing an app for both tablets and smartphones with fragments.

When app is executed on smartphone, I show a fragment with a list (categories). When clicking on an item, I start a new activity that holds a ViewPager that inflates Fragments with another list (detail).

When app is executed on tablet I have a layout with two fragments inside. The left one is the categories list and the right one is the detail list.

Up to here there's no problem, but when setting onOptionsItemSelected I have problems.

When executing app on smartphone, everything is working well. This works:

**Activity containing ViewPager**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icShare:
            sharePortal();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Fragment inflated by ViewPager**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icFavourite:
            Utils.setFavouritePortal(mContext, mPortal);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        case R.id.icShowFavourites:
            showFavouriteArticles();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But when executing the app in tablet, onOptionsItemSelected is not called. This is the code:

**Fragment containing ViewPager**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icShowFavourites:
            Log.e("asdf", "asdfasdf - test tablet");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Fragment inflated by ViewPager**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icFavourite:
            Utils.setFavouritePortal(mContext, mPortal);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        case R.id.icShowFavourites:
            showFavouriteArticles();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The only difference is that when executing on smartphone, the first onOptionsItemSelected is hold by an Activity and in tabled is hold by a fragment. I also tried to execute the onOptionsItemSelected from the Activity containing the fragment that contains the ViewPager inflating other fragments with no luck.

How can I get it working?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try to put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside the fragment where you want `onOptionsItemSelected()` to be called.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))

Comment: I forgot to say that I shady have implemented setHasMenuOptions.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment should call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`, and should implement `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Comment: I forgot to say that I shady have implemented setHasMenuOptions but I'll try to implement onCreateOptionsMenu.